# 2SXC/DNN - Delete ADAM Files in Entity

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dnn9

We're designing a system for a client where they are allowing authenticated users to upload images. We've created an API to upload the files but the client only wants the latest file and delete all previous ones so that there would only ever be one.

We've looked through the docs and can't come across a way for ADAM to handle this in both 2SXC and DNN's file system.

Internally when deleting images we see API calls like the following to the internal 2SXC API, but we're wondering if this is exposed somewhere within the public API?

https://somedomain.com/api/2sxc/app/auto/data/61393528-b401-411f-a001-f423ea46700a/b7d04e2c-c565-496c-8efb-aa133cf90d33/Photo/delete?subfolder=&isFolder=false&id=189&usePortalRoot=false&appId=3

We could probably use the same endpoint above, but we'd likely run into permission issues or changes to the APIs that could be problematic.

Thank you for any advice you can give! Perhaps @iJungleBoy can provide some thoughts on this.

Comment: I don't have a quick answer, and would probably need 1-2 hours to recommend something. So not something for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution from a completely different direction, if you are on the later release of 2sxc (v12.8+, v13+), and comfortable programming in C#, you might consider doing this as a "cleanup" from a Dnn Scheduled Task. This can be done with a relatively easy setup. We have a Gist in place that we use as a starter. You simply put the code in the /App_Code folder then setup a normal Dnn Scheduled Task. NOTE that you can scroll down to the first comment on the Gist to see a screenshot of a complete working setup.

[Accuraty's AccuTasks template on GitHub Gists](https://gist.github.com/accuraty-github/c8a363845e39d49c9279c58f7efcd6f4)

There are two more key things to note:

1. You need to install Dnn's CodeDom 3.6 because the example uses the later versions C#'s string interpolation - **OR** remove the few `$"ASL2021 - {this.GetType().Name}, Task Scheduled Email",` bits or convert to string.Format() or something.
2. Since your task's code is NOT running in a (2sxc) module, if needed, you'll do stuff like this: [2sxc Docs - Use 2sxc Instance or App Data from External C# Code](https://docs.2sxc.org/net-code/external/dotnet-external-use.html)

So, if you are comfortable writing code that "finds and deletes stuff older than NN days" - this might be the way to go.